# php preg_replace and newline characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

```
$s = "aaa";
echo preg_replace('/^(.*?)a$/s', "$1_", $s);

$s = "\t\t\t";
echo preg_replace('/^(.*?)\t$/s', "$1_", $s);

$s = "\n\n\n";
echo preg_replace('/^(.*?)\n$/s', "$1_", $s);
```

The first one prints

```
aa_
```

and the second one

```
\t\t_
```

But the last one prints

```
\n_\n
```

Why?

Comment: in preg replace you need to escape your backslashes. Try: `echo preg_replace('/^(.*)?\\n$/s', "$1_", $s)`

Comment: `$` does not match the very end of string. Use `\z`, or add `D` modifier